# C string array function How call the function?

Tags: c

What Parameters should I give this function? I think it needs a string array but I don't know the exact syntax.

```
void write_file(char *result[], int len) 
{
..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char result[10];
write_file(&(result[0]), 10);
```

or

```
char result[10];
write_file(result, 10);
```

which is the same, as array identifier is simply the address of its first element

Answer (score 0):

Infact it does not need string array. In C, you can not send array to a function and also you can not return an array from a function. Solution? You can send "the" array's starting point and it's length. Then the receiver side can understand "the" array. About your question, you must send start position of the array as first argument and length of the array as the second argument.

Comment: In order to avoid confusion I'd use "pointer" instead of "start position". That might lead to him sending a 0 in place of a pointer :)

Answer (score -1):

`char *result[]` means an array of pointers to `char`. However the question is what is the meaning of the parameter `len`?

Normally with a function named something like `write_file()` the function would write a character string to an output and the `len` parameter would be the number of characters to write out.

To use this function as the function looks would mean something like:

```
char *myStrings[] = {
    "string 0",
    "string 1"
};

write_file (myStrings, 0);  // passing zero as len as unsure what it is.
```

Or something like:

```
char *myStrings[20];    // array of pointers to chars
int  iLoop;

for (iLoop = 0; iLoop < 20; iLoop++) {
    myStrings[iLoop] = malloc(1000);   // allocate a large buffer for each string
    read_string (myStrings[iLoop], 1000);  // some made up function to read a string
}

write_file (myStrings, 20);
```

What I suspect is that the function should actually be `void write_file(char *result, int len)` or it should be `void write_file(char result[], int len)` so that rather than accepting an array of pointers to char arrays (how strings are normally used in C) it should be accepting a pointer to a char array.

So the idea of `write_file()` would be to write a single string to a file rather than several strings.